# Using dequereusable cell overlapping the contents of uitableview cells after scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When i use dequeReusableCell and when i scroll down or up the contents of last cells (that goes out of visible screen) gets overlapped but works when i create new cell each time.
And i want to use dequereusble functionality.

Following code working but when i uncomment the portion of dequereusable problem appears again.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"Cell";

    //Code causing problem
    /*UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if(!cell)
    {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }*/

    //Code working fine
    UITableViewCell *cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    UILabel *titleLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 180, 20)];
    [titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]];

    UIImageView *headerImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200)];
    headerImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"offer_details.jpg"];

    UILabel *detailLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, 300, 20)];
    [detailLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];

    UIButton *callButton=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, 20, 20)];
    [callButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];

    MKMapView *mapView=[[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, 320, 200)];

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            [cell.contentView addSubview:headerImageView];
            [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
            titleLabel.text=@"Get great offer Upto 20% Off";
            titleLabel.frame=CGRectMake(10, 220, 230, 20);
            titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:251.0/255.0f green:78.0f/255.0f blue:8.0f/255.0f alpha:1];
            detailLabel.frame=CGRectMake(10, 240, 300, 20);
            detailLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
            detailLabel.text=@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.";
            [cell.contentView addSubview:detailLabel];
            break;
        case 1:
            titleLabel.text=@"Details";
            detailLabel.text=@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. ";
            [cell.contentView addSubview:detailLabel];
            break;
        case 2:
            titleLabel.text=@"Collection Methods";
            detailLabel.text=@"Call and Reserve";
            detailLabel.frame=CGRectMake(50, 30, 300, 20);
            [cell.contentView addSubview:detailLabel];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:callButton];
            break;
        case 3:
            titleLabel.text=@"Location";
            [cell.contentView addSubview:mapView];
            break;
        case 4:
            titleLabel.text=@"About us";
            detailLabel.text=@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.";
            [cell.contentView addSubview:detailLabel];
            break;
        case 5:
            titleLabel.text=@"Legal";
            detailLabel.text=@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.";
            [cell.contentView addSubview:detailLabel];

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    detailLabel.numberOfLines=0;
    [detailLabel sizeToFit];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:titleLabel];


    return cell;
}
```

EDIT:

Will i be able to use dequereusable cell because contents of my rows are not common? One row contain image , one contain mapview, one contain labels only. Thanx in advance.

EDIT2:

@HRM now its showing detail lable blank except first cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"Cell";

```
UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

//UITableViewCell *cell;

if(!cell)
{
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    UILabel *titleLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 180, 20)];
    [titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13]];
    titleLabel.tag=1001;

    [cell.contentView addSubview:titleLabel];
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
        {
            UIImageView *headerImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200)];
            headerImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"offer_details.jpg"];
            headerImageView.tag=1002;

            UILabel *detailLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, 300, 20)];
            [detailLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
            detailLabel.tag=1003;
            detailLabel.numberOfLines=0;
            [detailLabel sizeToFit];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:headerImageView];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:detailLabel];
        }
            break;

        case 1:
        {
            UILabel *detailLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, 300, 20)];
            [detailLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
            detailLabel.numberOfLines=0;
            [detailLabel sizeToFit];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:detailLabel];
            detailLabel.tag=1004;
        }
            break;
        case 2:
        {
            UILabel *detailLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, 300, 20)];
            [detailLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
            UIButton *callButton=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, 15, 15)];
            [callButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
            detailLabel.numberOfLines=0;
            [detailLabel sizeToFit];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:detailLabel];
            detailLabel.tag=1005;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:callButton];
        }
            break;
        case 3:
        {
            MKMapView *mapView=[[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, 320, 140)];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:mapView];
        }
            break;
        case 4:
        {
            UILabel *detailLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, 300, 20)];
            [detailLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
            detailLabel.tag=1006;
            detailLabel.numberOfLines=0;
            [detailLabel sizeToFit];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:detailLabel];
        }
            break;
        case 5:
        {
            UILabel *detailLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, 300, 20)];
            [detailLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
            detailLabel.tag=1007;
            detailLabel.numberOfLines=0;
            [detailLabel sizeToFit];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:detailLabel];
        }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}


switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
    {
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1001];
        UILabel *detailLabel=(UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1003];
        titleLabel.text=@"Get great offer Upto 20% Off";
        titleLabel.frame=CGRectMake(10, 210, 230, 20);
        titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:251.0/255.0f green:78.0f/255.0f blue:8.0f/255.0f alpha:1];
        detailLabel.frame=CGRectMake(10, 230, 300, 20);
        detailLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        detailLabel.text=@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.";
    }
        break;
    case 1:
    {
        UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1001];
        UILabel *detailLabel=(UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1004];
        titleLabel.text=@"Details";
        detailLabel.text=@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. ";
    }
        break;
    case 2:
    {
        UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1001];
        UILabel *detailLabel=(UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1005];
        titleLabel.text=@"Collection Methods";
        detailLabel.text=@"Call and Reserve";
        detailLabel.frame=CGRectMake(30, 30, 300, 20);

    }
        break;
    case 3:
    {
        UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1001];
        titleLabel.text=@"Location";
    }
        break;
    case 4:
    {
        UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1001];
        UILabel *detailLabel=(UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1006];
        titleLabel.text=@"About us";
        detailLabel.text=@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. \n\n   Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.";
    }
        break;
    case 5:
    {
        UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1001];
        UILabel *detailLabel=(UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1007];
        titleLabel.text=@"Legal";
        detailLabel.text=@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. \n\n   Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.";

    }
        break;
    default:
        break;
}





return cell;
```

}

Comment: why did u comment out the `if(!cell)` condition?

Comment: doesn't it related with resusable cell?

Comment: u have to make sure that the `dequeue` happens properly so u need that check.

Comment: Also, there appear memory leaks in the snippet u have posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, the tableView will reuse the existing cell, and in your code, you are trying to create new controls again and again and hence it will overlap. The best approach of doing this would be like this. Please go through this. Hope it helps.

UPDATE based on your comment.

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier= @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

//If tableView dont have cell available for reuse, then 
//create a new cell and attach the controls to it
if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if(indexPath.row == 0){

        UILabel *titleLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 180, 20)];
    [titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]];
        titleLabel.tag = 1002;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:titleLabel];
    }
}

//Now we have a cell object with controls attached. 
//Now to update the contents on the control, just get the control from cell 
//using its tag and set your data from datasource
if(indexPath.row == 0){
    UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1002];
    titleLabel.text = //Text from your datasource for this row
}
```

Please note that, you need to take care of the height also in heightForRowAtIndexPath. Same logic will be applied there too.

Comment: thanx for ur help, i think this is the right way but problem is that contents of my tableview cells are not common for all cells, so i cant add them before checking row number and therefore i will not be able to reuse cell. What you think?

Comment: Then you can create controls inside if(cell==nil) block by checking the row. ie if row==1, then create and attach imageView only..and in the below code, just use the same condition to retrieve the added control.

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check and let me know whether this works for u.

Comment: I'm checking..BTW, can u pls put ur break; statements inside the case block.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would recommend:

1. Create a custom `UITableViewCell` class, and in its `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` you create all the required subviews. You will also need to assign your subviews to properties for external use.
2. Tell your `UITableView` object to register either the class or a NIB in `viewDidLoad`.
3. In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you can then access the cell's properties and update them appropriately.

This way you're not recreating the cell or its subviews each time `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called.

Comment: use of custom uitableview cell will not be efficient because my cell structure is not common for all cells.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to remove the sub views from the content view of UITableViewCell in cellForRowAtInddexPath through objective-C enumeration.Look below code for reference.

```
for(UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews){  
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {  
        [view removeFromSuperview];   
    }
}
```